# Authoritative reference for tea brewing (time, temperature, concentration)

Tags: tea

There seems to be a lot of heterogeneity for tea brewing instructions. Some instruction references are overly broad with respect to the tea category (white/green/black/herbal), and sometimes teas come with instructions which miss one of the three parameters (time, temperature, concentration). Additionally, the concentration is often given in unhelpful units of measurement (spoons) which are not only imprecise, but can actually mean different masses for teas with different leaf sizes.

Of course I understand there are a lot of different teas, and particularly the aromatized blends can be manufacturer specific. Obviously indexing all of that would be infeasible.

But for the common and widespread tea types, is there some authoritative source which puts everything together and uses proper units? Even wikipedia often omits these details, and seldom has references for them.

I'm basically looking for steeping time, temperature, and concentration, for at least the following:

- Sencha
- Gyokuro
- Genmaicha
- Silver Needle
- Dragonwell (aka. Longjing)
- Anji Bai
- Oolong
- Darjeeling

Comment: In addition to the linked answer, I'll point out that time/temp can vary by specific brands/releases of specific tea leaves.  That is, one sencha can be 3min at 180F and another 1min at 185F.  You can't generalize like you want to in this question.  Instead, get your tea from a purveyor who labels the bag with time and temperature.

Comment: Additionally there are significant cultural differences in what constitutes a perfect tea. From personal experience, even if using the same tea, a perfect Chinese tea would contain a lot more tea leaves per amount of water that a perfect British tea.